# `php artisan down` throws uncaught 503 and yields an error page

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, octobercms, http-status-code-503

*Edit:* Accepted Issue on GitHub https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2830

---

I am using OctoberCMS which is based upon the Laravel PHP framework.
(I am a newbie to both).

Ultimately, I'm trying to script as much of the site update process as possible. That is, *update/upgrade the testing and live sites and upload my new code*. This entails being able to put the site into maintenance mode from the command line.

The top level directory for my website (`/var/www/website/`) contains the artisan php script.

Running `php artisan list` I get:

```
Available commands: 
    down    Put the application into maintenance mode 
    up      Bring the application out of maintenance mode
```

Within the OctoberCMS backend I can put the frontend into maintenance mode, and the chosen maintenance page is shown as expected.

When I enter `php artisan down` in the console I get `Application is now in maintenance mode.`, as expected. But when I reload the website, I get the following error:

> We're sorry, but an unhandled error occurred. Please see the details below.
>   `.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 41`
>      Type: Undefined
>      Exception: `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException`

```
\* 
\* @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException 
*/ 
public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
    { 
        if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance()) { 
            throw new HttpException(503); 
        } 
    return $next($request); 
    }
```

It would appear that Laravel/Symfony is doing what it should and throwing a `503 Service Unavailable`, but there is nothing to catch it and render the maintenance page.

So, two questions
1) Is this a bug? If so, in Laravel or October? Or have I done something wrong -- config setting...?
2) Assuming it won't be 'fixed' any time soon, how and where should I catch the `HttpException(503)` and yield the maintenance page?

There is what might be an answer in `Stackoverflow > '503 can't be overridden in L5.1'`, which appears to suggest editing/overriding `public function handle($request, Closure $next)` with a `try/catch/return-if-503` sequence. But is it a good idea to override a function of the CMS/framework? If so, how and where?

I have read [OctoberCMS > docs > services > Errors & Logging](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log) and, despite hoping for an easier solution, I would create a Plugin to solve the problem if that is the best/only/ideal way. Although creating a Plugin to catch what should surely already be caught seems overkill.

This looks to be the way to do it [Laravel - Pass arguments to php artisan down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805599/laravel-pass-arguments-to-php-artisan-down), but I'm not confident to attempt it.

---

Turnkey LAMP 14.1 server

October system build 414

`php --version`
`PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 08:50:21)`

`php artisan --version`
`Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)`

Comment: I would say that displaying the maintenance page should be something handled by October when `artisan down` is run. Make an issue for this on the Github (https://github.com/octobercms/october) and it'll get looked at

Comment: Thank you, @Luke. Looking at your profile I'm confident to accept that this is an October issue and do as you suggest. Although, in https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2768, you state that you use `php artisan down;` suggesting that the issue doesn't affect you.

Comment: I haven't checked it in a while, plus that process doesn't take that long to begin with so the application isn't down for a while.